# Dots are not appending to right graph?

Tags: d3.js

I am having a problem with my code where the circle nodes that I have created do not seem to be appending themselves to the graph. The debugger isn't pulling up any errors, so it seems like it's a logic issue. 
Here's what is looks like:

```
(dot)
|
|
|
|
|
|       <--(where dot should be)
|
 __________________________________________
               ^
               |
             graph
```

And here's my code:

```
<script>
                        var slider = $("#myRange").val();;
                        var xtwo;
                        var xone;
                        var xzero;
                        var firstx = -1;
                        var firsty = 1;
                        var secondx = 2;
                        var secondy = 4;
                        var lineData = [];
                        var nodes = [];

                        //updates coefficients
                        function updateXs() {
                            xtwo = (75 - slider) / 50;
                            xone = (slider - 25) / 50;
                            xzero = (slider - 25) / 25;
                        }

                        //gets corresponding y from x and coefficients
                        function getY(xval) {
                            return (xval * xval * xtwo + xval * xone + xzero);
                        }

                        function displayVals() {
                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = slider + " " + xtwo + " " + xone + " " + xzero + "   " + lineData;
                        }

                        function updateLineData() {
                            //resets and fills points
                            lineData = [];
                            for (i = (firstx - 1); i < (secondx + 2); i++) {
                                lineData.push({
                                    x: i,
                                    y: getY(i)
                                });
                            }

                        }
                        //makes dots for static points
                        function makeDots(xvalue, xvalue2) {
                            nodes = [{
                                x: xvalue,
                                y: getY(xvalue)
                            }, {
                                x: xvalue2,
                                y: getY(xvalue2)
                            }]

                        }

                        function makeLine() {}

                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            updateXs();
                            updateLineData();
                            displayVals();



                            var vis = d3.select('#visual'),
                                WIDTH = 1000,
                                HEIGHT = 500,
                                MARGINS = {
                                    top: 20,
                                    right: 20,
                                    bottom: 20,
                                    left: 50
                                },
                                xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function(d) {
                                    return d.x;
                                }), d3.max(lineData, function(d) {
                                    return d.x;
                                })]),
                                yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function(d) {
                                    return d.y;
                                }), d3.max(lineData, function(d) {
                                    return d.y;
                                })]),
                                xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                .scale(xRange)
                                .tickSize(5)
                                .tickSubdivide(true),
                                yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                .scale(yRange)
                                .tickSize(5)
                                .orient("left")
                                .tickSubdivide(true);


                            vis.append("svg:g")
                                .attr("class", "x axis")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
                                .call(xAxis);

                            vis.append("svg:g")
                                .attr("class", "y axis")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
                                .call(yAxis);



                            var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
                                .x(function(d) {
                                    return xRange(d.x);
                                })
                                .y(function(d) {
                                    return yRange(d.y);
                                })
                                .interpolate('basis');

                            vis.append("svg:path")
                                .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData))
                                .attr("stroke", "blue")
                                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                                .attr("fill", "none");

                            makeDots(firstx, secondx);




                            //puts in dots
                              vis.selectAll("circle.nodes")
                                .data(nodes)
                                .enter()
                                .append("circle")
                                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                                    console.log(d.x)
                                    return 200;
                                })
                                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                                    return d.y;
                                })
                                .attr("r", "10px")
                                .attr("fill", "black")

                            //updates when slider changes
                            $("#myRange").change(function() {
                                slider = $("#myRange").val();

                                updateXs();
                                updateLineData();
                                displayVals();
                            });


                        });

                    </script>
```

Please help and thanks in advance. Also, I was wondering if I could get some tips on how to make the line move using the .change function

Comment: My first comment is that your d3 code is VERY not standard. Its not that there is a right or wrong way. If your code works all is good. But if it doesn't, its good to follow best practices so that others can more easily read your code. My second comment is that I can be more helpful if I see the HTML your code is working with as well. Easy ways to share code are jsfiddle, github gists, plunker, etc...

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's the jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0oyhy8mw/1/)

Comment: Alright I've looked it over a bit more. A couple things that you are doing are making d3 much much more difficult than it ordinarily would be. I updated your fiddle to use `lineData` as the data you are making circles from and applied xRange and yRange to both d.x and d.y in the functions which define cx and cy. It's probably closer to what you want but not exactly. I hope you look further into d3 and work with it to get a better grasp on whats going on. https://jsfiddle.net/0oyhy8mw/3/

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the idea was that there should be two dots, and the slider modifies a quadratic equation that goes through them, but I'll work on it myself and see if I can do it.

Comment: @gamehen, the reason your line doesn't go through the dots is because you are [interpolating](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate) using a spline.  If you want a smooth curve, I wouldn't interpolate but rather overfit the curve (supply it lots of points).  See  my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't applied your scale function to your dots:

```
vis.selectAll(".nodes")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .attr("cx", function (d) {
    return xRange(d.x); //<-- convert from user space to pixel space
  })
  .attr("cy", function (d) {
    return yRange(d.y); //<-- convert from user space to pixel space
  });
```

To make your line update, you need to select it and change the `d` attribute:

```
d3.select(".myLine") //<-- select it by some unique class
  .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData)); //<-- update the d attribute
```

To get a smooth curve without interpolation, just supply more points.  See udpated fiddle.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0oyhy8mw/6/).

Comment: Thanks Mark. You have no idea how much time I have spent struggling with this one problem and your help really means a lot.